# Ruby on Rails - simple_form - How do I change an input into a multiple choice dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I currently have a simple_form set up and one of my inputs is:

```
<%= form.input :contract, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Contract Type", label: false %>
```

However I would instead like to change it into a dropdown with 3 options - full time, part time and internship.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: append `collection: ['full time', 'part time', 'internship'], input_html: {multiple: true}` to form input, and then use http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ to it for ui

Comment: awesome, however that starts with an empty dropdown box. How would I get it to display 'Contract type' in the box from the start?

Comment: i have updated the comment. add `mutiple: true` inside `input_html`

Comment: No, no I wanted the first outcome but for it to display Contract Type inside the input field like in this link under the selection section where it has Gender showing as a placeholder in the input and then you click the box to display the options - http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Comment: ok then remove `multiple: true` and add `input_html:{class: "ui dropdown"}, prompt: "Contract Type"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<%= form.input :contract, collection: ['full time', 'part time', 'internship'], input_html: { class: "ui dropdown", maxlength: 60, }, prompt: "Contract Type", label: false %>
```